# Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on path 1.8.0-nullsafety.1

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently updated the Flutter version from my previous version to 2.0, but with few exceptions occurring I decided to downgrade back to where my flutter version was(1.22.6) on stable channel.

now I get this error on pub get
*Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on path 1.8.0-nullsafety.1 and PawFect depends on path ^1.8.0, flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.
So, because PawFect depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because PawFect depends on flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)*

my **pubspec.yaml** looks like this now.

```yaml
...
version: 1.0.25+7

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  #Firebase Core API
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0

  #firebase analytics
  firebase_analytics: ^7.0.1

  #firebase crashlytics
  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.4.0+1

  #firebase performance
  firebase_performance: ^0.5.0+1

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  shimmer: ^1.1.2
  lite_rolling_switch: ^0.1.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
#  country_code_picker: ^1.7.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+21
  connectivity: ^3.0.3
#  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1
#  gallery_saver: ^2.0.1
    #  camera: ^0.5.8+5
  path: ^1.8.0
  http: ^0.12.2
  toggle_switch: ^0.1.8
  pie_chart: ^5.0.0
  fl_chart: ^0.20.1
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.9
  simple_animations: ^2.4.2
  package_info: ^0.4.3+2
#  dio: ^3.0.10
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+3
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
  get_it: ^6.0.0
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.4
  mime: ^0.9.7
  http_parser: ^3.1.4
  flutter_image_compress: ^0.7.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  device_preview: ^0.7.1
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.6
  in_app_purchase: ^0.3.5+1
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
#  rename: ^1.3.0
  expansion_tile_card: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.2
  provider: ^4.3.2+4
#  number_display: ^2.3.0
#  functional_widget_annotation: ^0.8.0
#  stripe_payment: ^1.0.9

flutter_icons:
#  android: "launcher_icon"
  image_path: "assets/images/pawfect_logo.png"
#  image_path_android: "assets/images/logo_large.png"
#  image_path_ios: "assets/images/logo_large.png"
  android: true # can specify file name here e.g. "ic_launcher"
  ios: true # can specify file name here e.g. "My-Launcher-Icon"
#  adaptive_icon_background: "assets/images/christmas-background.png" # only available for Android 8.0 devices and above
#  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/images/icon-foreground-432x432.png" # only available for Android 8.0 devices and above

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
..
```

How can I resolve this error, and get dependencies without an issue.?

**flutter doctor**

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H114 darwin-x64,
    locale en-GB)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

Comment: Change your `path: ^1.8.0` dependency to `path: ^1.8.0-0` to allow accepting development versions of 1.8.0.  `path: ^1.8.0` means that you accept only *stable* versions of `path` 1.8.0 (or later), but `flutter_test` depends on a development version.

Comment: that worked out, and I reset the rest of the packages into older versions I used. now I get an error on imports. no suggestion to import the packages even

Comment: Could you elaborate about the error you've encountered after you've resolve the original error?

Answer (score 0):

`flutter_test` seems to require null safety from at least 1.8.0 to work properly, and the error was thrown when the Flutter version that you're using was downgraded. There's a [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/104181) filed to document this behavior. The workaround on this issue is to manage the versions that you're using to at least match the minimum dependency set.